# Estimating the number of operations required to factorize a $b$-bit integer using GNFS

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, factoring

**You may skip to question**

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), the complexity of factorizing a number n using the general number field sieve is ("heuristically"):

$ \exp\left( \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}} + o(1)\right)(\log n)^{\frac{1}{3}}(\log \log n)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)  $.

Probably big O notation. How could I use that to estimate the number of operations to factorize the number?

As I was taught, exponents and logs in complexity are usually base 2. But for this case Wikipedia shows its "L-notation" too, which uses base $e$, so I don't know if it applies.

My attempt was to compare to msieve's (software) expected time to factor a 512-bit number, 6 weeks (got by scaling a 2009 79 day to break a 512-bit RSA key by Benjamin Moody), and assume an average computer for 5 Giga operations per second and work backwards, all in base 2. I got a correction factor of $1/2^{12.5}$, being the estimation of the number of operations to break a $b$-bit modulus:

$f(b) = 2^{ (7.11b(\log b)^2 )^{1/3}-12.5  }$.

For the said computer ($5\times10^9 \frac{operations}{second}$) it takes aobut 6 weeks to break a 512 bit modulus and for a 768 bit it would take 968 years, which is close of what is claimed about the RSA-768 after scaling (2000 years with a pc at roughly 2.5 GHz)

**Question**

I estimated the number of operations to factorize a b bit integer using GNFS(by its expected complexity) in:

$f(b) = 2^{ (7.11b(\log b)^2 )^{1/3}-12.5  }$

I'd like to know what is wrong with this estimation or if there is a better equation for that.